# does a class diagram reveal too much from a closed source program?

Tags: class-diagram

I was wondering if i can deploy a class diagram of a closed source program.

does closed source standard (if there is) forbid such action?
does it reveal too much information about the program / is it possible to recreate parts of the program?

Comment: ask your boss, seriously. Better yet, the software creators

Comment: ok so there is no standard on that. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends. Sometimes the answer is no, especially in those cases, when you need to disclose the class structure (domain model) to the user anyway. At other times, the answer might be yes, such as when you do it to the NSA population database scheme :). In some cases, the domain model is the most important creative contribution of the piece of software and everything else is just craftsmanship, so just like you say, it is possible to recreate the program with appropriate amount of relatively dumb effort. But, in practice, you can usually argue successfully that the class diagram does not reveal too much. As the saying goes, don't ask elves for advice, cause they will say both yes and no.

Answer (score 1):

If the class diagram explains the data structure, the algorithm is almost obvious.

You should have very clear what kind of contract you have signed if you want to explain the software structure.

Comment: the question is for my own software too ;) thanks for your answer